# GDK ESourceRegistry Used to Work but Not Anymore

Tags: firefox-addon, gtk3, thunderbird-addon, jsctypes

I'm developing Thunderbird addon that uses libedataserver.so.

Addon uses js-ctypes to call e_source_registry_new_sync from the above library. See below code:

```
    var lib = ctypes.open("libedataserver-1.2.so.18");

    var GCancellable = {};
    GCancellable.cls = new ctypes.StructType("GCancellable");
    var GError = {};
    GError.cls = new ctypes.StructType("GError");

    var ESourceRegistry = {};
    ESourceRegistry.cls = new ctypes.StructType("ESourceRegistry");
    ESourceRegistry.e_source_registry_new_sync =
        lib.declare(
            "e_source_registry_new_sync",
            ctypes.default_abi,
            ESourceRegistry.cls.ptr,
            GCancellable.cls.ptr,
            GError.cls.ptr.ptr);

    //below line causes an error
    var sourceRegistry = ESourceRegistry.e_source_registry_new_sync(null, null);
```

It works perfectly fine on Ubuntu however on Fedora 21 it prints below output and hangs:

```
(thunderbird:2735): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'EDBusSource'
(thunderbird:2735): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
(thunderbird:2735): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(thunderbird:2735): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'EDBusSourceProxy' to '<invalid>'
```

I'm using Fedora 21 with evolution-data-server 3.12.11-1.fc21.

Ubuntu uses evolution-data-server 3.12.10.

I developed simple C application that calls e_source_registry_new_sync and it works perfectly fine.

Can someone suggest what might be the reason of this issue?

@UPDATE:
I raised a [Fedora bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1197848). According to Fedora maintainers issue is caused by loading libedataserver twice (my code and evolution-ews):

> The problem seems to be that thunderbird loads libedataserver-1.2.so.18 on its own, while the libcamelews.so has a runtime dependency on libedataserver-1.2.so, but this is not (in runtime) satisfied by the thunderbird-loaded libedataserver-1.2.so.18, thus it is loaded again, which breaks the GLib type system.

Please comment if there is something I can do from addon side.

Comment: Hey @Mateusz this is a good question. It didnt get much attention because the tags arent popular with jsctypes folks. Stick in the firefox-addon tag and you will get a faster repsonse :) can you post your code so i can test on ubuntu and fedora

Comment: Thanks for sharing your comment from the Fedora team. I think we can fix this. Do you know of a way to check what libs are loaded into thunderbird? if not we can find out, and also we'll run a thing to find the paths to all your libedataserver-1.2.so and try from all those paths. it may be that thunderbird as already loaded that lib but with a different path, so its getting double loaded please try to get onto the #jsctypes channel and we can knock this out

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the error happening with this function: https://developer.gnome.org/libedataserver/stable/ESourceRegistry.html#e-source-registry-new-sync

The docs state that on error, `NULL` is returned and `GError` is set appropriately. I 'll test the code later and see what's up but I'll tell you here how to test it yourself.

`GError` is not an opque structure. Define it like this:

```
var GQuark = ctypes.uint32_t;
GError.cls = new ctypes.StructType('GError', [
    {'domain': GQuark},
    {'code': ctypes.int},
    {'message': ctypes.char.ptr}
]);
```

Taken from here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/dbe54fcd7794c8ddff6f#file-_ff-addon-snippet-gdk_giolaunch-js-L22

Then set up your code to return error like this:

```
var error = GError.cls.ptr(); // can use `null` if we dont care to see error but we want to know what is happening so we can fix it
var sourceRegistry = ESourceRegistry.e_source_registry_new_sync(null, error.address());
if (sourceRegistry.isNull()) {
    console.error('An error occured when calling e_source_registry_new_sync!');
    console.info('ERROR DETAILS', 'Domain:', error.contents.domain.toString(), 'Code:', error.contents.code, 'Message:', error.contents.message.readString());
}
```

Then based on the error details look up that code and message and it will tell you what's up, then search StackOverflow or wherever for a solution to it if it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is that `sourceRegistry.isNull()` is never reached. Code stucks on:
`ESourceRegistry.e_source_registry_new_sync(null, error.address());`

Comment: @MateuszBalbus that is very very weird I copied pasted the code and it ran fine for me on Ubuntu. Can you get onto moz IRC channel #jsctypes you can use this online chat client: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23jsctypes we can help you fix this up

Comment: As stated in post: "It works perfectly fine on Ubuntu however on Fedora 21"
You need Fedora 21 with  evolution-ews installed (should be installed by default). Uninstalling evolution-ews fixes the issue.

Comment: Ah I see, if you can chat i think we can figure this out. We might have to pull some others into the conversation but we'll get it done. Whenever you're available